# Omitting a pronoun from a cleft sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis, pronouns, omissibility, clefts

I believe this is
[a cleft sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence):

1. It was 10:18 ᴀᴍ  **when** it happened.

However, I cannot explain why the pronoun *when* can’t
be removed when you rewrite that sentence into this one:

2. When it (=*the robbery*) happened, it (=*the time*) was 10:18 ᴀᴍ.

Can someone help me understand the structure of this sentence
that explains why *when* can’t be removed from it?

Comment: Since _when_ is obviously needed in your rewritten version, why do you want to omit it from the original? Anyway, _when_ is an adverb, not a pronoun.

Comment: The basic structure is not (2) but rather *It [the robbery] happened at 10:18.* In (2) you are fronting time (*When*) and in (1) the actual time (*10:18*). You could omit *When* with *Ten eighteen was the time of the robbery*

Comment: The *when* can be omitted if you use *that* to introduce the cleft (if this is, in fact a cleft). Although in that case I have a slight preference for using *at 10:18*: *It was (at) 10:18 that it happened.*

Comment: Are you asking why "when" cannot be omitted in 1. or 2? Btw, "when" is a preposition here.